# How to add a resize handle on the left boundary of a textbox?

Tags: css, dojo, resize

I want to have a textbox with two y-axis resize handles like this:
[image]

I tried to add a Dojo ResizeHandle, but it attaches to the right boundary of the textbox even if I place it on the left boundary with CSS. i.e. I want the left resize handle to resize the textbox with left boundary.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

My css at the moment looks like this:

```
float: left;
position: relative;
right: 4px;
bottom: 6px;
width: 6px;
height: 6px;
z-index: 20;
background-image: url(dojox/images/resize.png);
line-height: 0px;
```

Is there a better way to attach the handle to the left boundary with CSS or Dojo?

Comment: place the label inside the **div** and make **div** as re-sizable.no need any js for this .only we can do it in css [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/wrjpoecb/1/) .this one approach

Comment: @yugi, the **div** in your approach can only resize the label/div on the **right boundary**. But I need to use the **left resize handle** to resize the label on the **left boundary**.